# How to make a label cycle through preset words or phrases when a button is pressed in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

So I'm trying to make it cycle through each letter of the alphabet when the button is clicked.
I have tried the method i am showing now.
I have also tried many others and i couldn't get anything to work.
If you do have a solution please try keep it simple i am kinda new too this.

````
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.title('ab')
a = 0
def changetext():
    a = a+1
    if a == 1:
        lbl.config(text='b')
def changetext():
    if a == 2:
        lbl.config(text='c')

lbl = Label(win,text='a')
lbl.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn = Button(win,text='u', command =changetext)
btn.grid(row=2,column=1)
win.mainloop()```
````

Comment: You should read on global vs local variables in python. In your `changetext()` function, `a` is local so the value of the variable `a` outside the function is not changed.

Comment: im confused so you mean i must make an external script so it can fetch from that one instead of using the ones inside the main script and if so how would i go about doing that

Comment: See my answer below, I am not talking about an external script, I am talking about the variables modified inside the function, but maybe reading https://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually used the first method and adapted it by making the variable global because then it will update it for all the functions making my first method work

```
from tkinter import *
win = Tk()
win.title('ab')
i = 0
def changetext():
    global i
    i = i + 1
    if i == 1:
        lbl.config(text='word 2')
    if i == 2:
        lbl.config(text='word 1 ')



lbl = Label(win,text='a')
lbl.grid(row=1,column=1)
btn = Button(win,text='u', command =changetext)
btn.grid(row=2,column=1)
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, variables inside functions are local, which means that if you define a variable `a = 0` outside the function, then do `a = 1` in the function, the `a` equals 1 inside the function but it still equals 0 outside. If you want to change the value of `a` outside the function from inside the function, you need to declare `a` as a global variable (see code below).

```
import tkinter as tk  # avoid import * to because it leads to naming conflicts
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('ab')

i = 0
letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def changetext():
    global i  # change value of i outside function as well
    i += 1
    i %= 26  # cycle through the alphabet
    lbl.configure(text=letters[i])

lbl = tk.Label(win, text='a')
lbl.grid(row=1, column=1)
btn = tk.Button(win,text='u', command=changetext)
btn.grid(row=2, column=1)
win.mainloop()
```

Comment: so because it was only begin defined in side the def function the other functions didnt know weather it was changing or not

Comment: @HyperStrike1212 yes

Comment: how would i cycle through words or sentances, is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.cycle` to create a cycle list and then use `next()` function to get the next item in the cycle list:

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle

words = cycle(['hello', 'world', 'python', 'is', 'awesome'])

root = tk.Tk()

lbl = tk.Label(root, text=next(words), width=20)
lbl.pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Next', command=lambda: lbl.config(text=next(words))).pack()

root.mainloop()
```